# Marquee text direction to rtl

Tags: html, marquee

I have problem changing the text direction to rtl (right-to-left) in a marquee. Here's the code:

```
<marquee direction="left" behavior="alternate" scrollamount="1" class="qus" dir="rtl">some text علي</marquee>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bJ7Ux/)

It does not move but when I remove the `dir="rtl"` it works fine . . . but I need the `dir="rtl"`.

Answer (score 1):

according to http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/rendering.html#the-marquee-element

The direction attribute has nothing to do with the text direction and only deals with the animation.

http://jsfiddle.net/austinpray/pzDfV/

```
<marquee direction="right"  behavior="alternate" scrollamount="1" class="qus">some text علي</marquee>
```

That works just fine.

Marquees are so bad. I would reconsider using them at all.

Answer (score 0):

Put the rtl in a div instead:

```
<marquee direction="left"  behavior="alternate" scrollamount="1" class="qus" ><div style="direction:rtl;">some text علي</div></marquee>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no attribute "dir" in marquee you can use direction "rtl"  or direction right and the alternative of marquee you can use it [liScroll](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use maquee! It is a deprecated element... If you absolutely must use it, do it in CSS.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mrSw/)

**CSS**

> body {font:12px arial, helvetica, sans-serif;} .marquee { width:130px;
>   height:40px; padding:1px; background-color: red; border: 1px solid
>   black; white-space: nowrap;  overflow: hidden;
>
> overflow-x:-webkit-marquee;
>   -webkit-marquee-direction: backwards;
>   -webkit-marquee-style: scroll;
>   -webkit-marquee-speed: fast;
>   -webkit-marquee-increment: small;
>   -webkit-marquee-repetition: infinite;
>
> overflow-x: marquee-line; marquee-direction: forward; marquee-style:
>   scroll; marquee-speed: fast; marquee-play-count: infinite; }

**HTML**

```
<div class="marquee">
<p>some text علي</p>
</div>
```

**SWITCHING DIRECTION**

Simply swap forwards for backwards in the CSS.
[JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3mrSw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute `"dir"` in marquee, you can use direction attribute to swap the `direction="left"` by `direction="right"`.